# Button under ListView not visible in Android

Tags: android, xml-layout

I am working on some `ListView` I want to display a `Button` under it I am using the following code but that is not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the button is not visible, why?

Comment: Try giving it a defined width value instead of wrap_content, i.e. '150dp'.

Comment: I tried this and the listview bled into the button area.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

List view takes the full page. Try to give desired weight to the elements to your code. Use this code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:layout_weight="5" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Nicer to use android:layout_weight instead of android:weight.

Answer (score 9):

This is happening because `ListView` has height set to `wrap_content`, which makes it extend to accommodate all items leaving no space on the screen for the button.  You can use relative layout setting the button along the bottom and then the listview to occupy the remaining space:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:layout_above="@id/button1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This will make the button float at the bottom of the screen always. Not the effect where you can scroll the list and find the button.

Comment: But that's not what the op was asking about.

Answer (score 6):

I have added this line.............. 
android:weight="1" ..........
within the list view as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" 
    android:weight="1" 
/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should write down your changes, we have to find diferrences in yours and OP code

Comment: I have added this line.............. android:weight="1" ..........within the list view

Answer (score 1):

For this the button and the listview should be in a same linearlayout, if all views are in relative layout, add the listview and button to a linear layout and give listview weight as 1, this worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_shipping_address"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background_all"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.reallymake.android.pottery.ShippingAddressActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
    android:text="@string/ok"
      />

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/btn_add_new_address"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_addresses"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/list"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/lv_addresses"
        android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:text="@string/proceed" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding weight, or aligning bottom will make the button float at the bottom of the screen always. And the list will go below it.

If want to display the button after scroll down the list, then add the button as a footer to the list view.